# Recursive conditional types

Tags: typescript

I'd like to map an object recursively so that the primitive values in the object are converted to some other type.

For example, I'd like an object like this:

```
const before = { a: { c: '' }, b: [ '', { d: '' } ] }
```

to become this:

```
const after = { a: { c: Test }, b: [ Test, { d: Test } ] }
```

*I'm also assuming that values won't be `Date`, `Symbol`, or null/void. Just JSON serializable types like string, numbers, etc. (except null)*

Here's what I tried:

```
type ConvertToTest<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any[]
        ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
        : T[P] extends {}
            ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
            : Test;
}

function convert<T>(o: T): ConvertToTest<T> {
    // ...
}
```

*This is using the [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) introduced in Typescript 2.8.*

`const after = convert(before)` results in `after.a.c` with `string` type completions in the editor for `c`, instead of completions for `Test`.

How do I rewrite `type ConvertToTest<T>` to convince Typescript that `after.a.c` is of type `Test`?

**EDIT:** Here's a [Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Test%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20'bar'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ConvertToTest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20any%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20ConvertToTest%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20ConvertToTest%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20Test%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20convert%3CT%3E(o%3A%20T)%3A%20ConvertToTest%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20before%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%20''%20%7D%2C%20b%3A%20%5B''%2C%20%7B%20d%3A%20''%20%7D%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20after%20%3D%20convert(before)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aafter.a.c.foo%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aafter.a.c.fontsize%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong) illustrating the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you need two things from the `ConvertToTest<T>` type. One is that if `T` is a primitive type, then `CovertToTest<T> = Test`. The other is that if `T` isn't primitive, you want to keep the same keys but convert their values.

To do that, I'd just add the first case as one part of a conditional type, and then have the other branch use a recursive mapped type:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
type ConvertToTest<T> = T extends Primitive ? Test : {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends (infer U)[] ? ConvertToTest<U>[] :
        ConvertToTest<T[K]>;
}
```

Using that, you can then use it like so:

```
// For example. Replace with whatever your actual type is.
type test = {
    foo(): string;
}

declare function convertToTest<T>(obj: T): ConvertToTest<T>;
const test = convertToTest({ a: "", b: { c: true, primArr: [1, ""], objArr: [{inner: ""}] } });

test.a.foo(); // OK
test.b.c.foo(); // OK
test.b.primArr[0].foo() // OK
test.b.objArr[0].inner.foo() // OK
```

This is a nice way to do it since it will work for objects of any depth, and will properly handle converting the elements of an array type as well.

Comment: What's the meaning of `infer U`?

Comment: The `infer U` tells typescript to extract the element type of the array for use later. This is what allows the type to correctly convert, say, `string[]` to `Test[]`, while at the same time allowing `{foo: string}[]` to convert to `{foo: Test}[]`. Without it, you would lose type info when trying to convert an object that had an array in it, since typescript wouldn't know how to convert the array elements properly (since it wouldn't know their type).

Comment: You can read about the new `infer` keyword [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

Answer (score 0):

changing the type to

```
type ConvertToTest<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any[]
        ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
        : T[P] extends string
            ? Test
            : ConvertToTest<T[P]>
}
```

(`extends string` instead of `extends {}`) or

```
type ConvertToTest<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any[]
        ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
        : T[P] extends object
            ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
            : Test    
}
```

(`extends object` instead of `extends {}`)

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close. The problem here is that `string` is assignable to `{}`.

Demonstration of this fact [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20A%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20Object%20%3F%20%7Ba%7D%20%3A%20%7Bb%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20(%7B%7D%20as%20A%3C''%3E)%3B%0D%0At.a%3B%0D%0At.b%3B).

If you check for the string, number, etc. first before `{}`, then you can get what you want:

```
type ConvertToTest<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any[]
        ? ConvertToTest<T[P]>
        : T[P] extends string
        ? Test
        : T[P] extends number
        ? Test
        : T[P] extends boolean
        ? Test
        : ConvertToTest<T[P]>
}
```