# Convert nested array type

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm looking for a type that can be used to convert a nested array type of arbitrary depth to another type. So some type, `ConvertToBool<T>` such that:

```
ConvertToBool<number[][][]> // should be boolean[][][]
```

I managed to get this working for non-nested array types, and for object types. I even wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051582/recursive-conditional-types/50051970#50051970) for converting the fields of an object type, and it works well except for the case of nested arrays.

Now I wanted to write a type like this:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;

type ConvertToBool<T> =
    T extends Primitive ? boolean :
    T extends (infer U)[] ? ConvertToBool<U>[] : // <-- Problem Line
    {[K in keyof T]: ConvertToBool<T[K]>};
```

But since a type alias cannot circularly reference itself, this doesn't work. Does anyone know of a workaround to automatically convert the type of an arbitrarily nested array type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is a known limitation, but it specifically has a workaround for anything like `Array<>` which is an `interface`.  See the definition of `DeepReadonly<T>` from @[ahejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg)'s [pull request introducing conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issue-164138025):

```
type DeepReadonly<T> =
    T extends any[] ? DeepReadonlyArray<T[number]> :
    T extends object ? DeepReadonlyObject<T> :
    T;

interface DeepReadonlyArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}

type DeepReadonlyObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};
```

As mentioned in the text:

> Similar to union and intersection types, conditional types are not permitted to reference themselves recursively (however, **indirect references through interface types or object literal types are allowed** *[emphasis mine]*, as illustrated by the `DeepReadonly<T>` example above).

---

So, for your case, we can do this:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;

interface ConvertToBoolArray<T> extends Array<ConvertToBool<T>> {}

type ConvertToBool<T> =
  T extends Primitive ? boolean :
  T extends (infer U)[] ? ConvertToBoolArray<U> : // okay now
  { [K in keyof T]: ConvertToBool<T[K]> };
```

And let's see it work:

```
declare const c: ConvertToBool<{ a: number, b: string[], c: { d: number }[] }>;
c.a // boolean
c.b[2] // boolean
c.c[3].d // boolean

type BoolBoolBool = ConvertToBool<number[][][]>
declare const bbb: BoolBoolBool;
bbb[0][1][2] === true; // okeydokey
```

This works, with the caveat that `BoolBoolBool` doesn't look like `boolean[][][]` when you inspect it; it is `ConvertToBoolArray<number[][]>`, but those are equivalent:

```
type IsSame<T extends V, U extends T, V=U> = true;
// IsSame<T, U> only compiles if T extends U and U extends T:

declare const sameWitness: IsSame<BoolBoolBool, boolean[][][]> // works
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same technique @jcalz (thank you) mentioned to convert any Date to a string and it worked very good

```js
    type PrimitiveType = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | never;
    export type ConvertDateToString<T> =
       T extends Date ? string :
       T extends PrimitiveType ? T :
       T extends Array<infer U> ? Array<ConvertDateToString<U>> :
       { [K in keyof T]: ConvertDateToString<T[K]> };
```