# Conditional Typescript - converting values within nested Objects/Arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `convertStudentObjectToStudentString` that traverses a given input (so for an object or array, it would traverse all nested keys or elements) and convert any `Student` instance it finds into a simple string.

I'm not sure how to describe the input and output types of that function. If the function receives a Student, I can immediately return a string. However, if the function receives and object or array, it should return a similar object/array with the same keys unless the value happens to be a Student.

```
class Student {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const alice = new Student('Alice');
const bob = new Student('Bob');

const school = {
    students: [
        alice,
        bob
    ],
    chemistryClass: {
        students: [alice]
    },
    prefect: bob,
}

function convertStudentObjectToStudentString<T>(input: T): T extends Student ? string : T {
    if (input instanceof Student) return input.name;
    if (typeof input !== 'object') return input;
    if (Array.isArray(input)) return input.map(convertStudentObjectToStudentString);
    return Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, k) => ({
        ...acc,
        [k]: convertStudentObjectToStudentString(input[k]),
    }), {});
}

console.log(school);
console.log(convertStudentObjectToStudentString(school));
// {
//   "students": ["Alice", "Bob"],
//   "chemistryClass": {
//      "students": ["Alice"]
//    },
//   "prefect": "Bob"
// }

const physicsStudents = [bob, alice];
console.log(convertStudentObjectToStudentString(physicsStudents));
// [ "Bob", "Alice" ]
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sm5gqz

Answer (score 0):

Function [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) may fit your case.

```
function convertStudentObjectToStudentString<T extends Student>(input: T): string;
function convertStudentObjectToStudentString<T>(input: T): T;
function convertStudentObjectToStudentString(input: any): any {
    if (input instanceof Student) return input.name;
    if (typeof input !== 'object') return input;
    if (Array.isArray(input)) return input.map(convertStudentObjectToStudentString);
    return Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, k) => ({
        ...acc,
        [k]: convertStudentObjectToStudentString(input[k]),
    }), {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While playing around some more and understanding my own problem more, I found my answer here: [Recursive conditional types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051582/recursive-conditional-types)

This seems to work quite well.

```
type ConvertToString<T> = T extends Student ? string : {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends (infer U)[] ? ConvertToString<U>[] :
        ConvertToString<T[K]>;
}

function convertStudentObjectToStudentString<T>(input: T): ConvertToString<T>
function convertStudentObjectToStudentString(input: any): any {
    if (input instanceof Student) return input.name;
    if (typeof input !== 'object') return input;
    if (Array.isArray(input)) return input.map(convertStudentObjectToStudentString);
    return Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, k) => ({
        ...acc,
        [k]: convertStudentObjectToStudentString(input[k]),
    }), {});
}
```